# Mongoose model get undefined properties after population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, swagger, mongoose-populate

I got a problem for a basic request.
All properties of a mongoose model I fetch are undefined in the exec() callback.

Here is my schema :

```
userSchema: new Schema({
    email: { type: String, limit: 50, index: true },
    password: String,
    birthdate: { type: Date },
    active: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    friends: [{
      _friend: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      addedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }],
    registrationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  })
```

You can already notice that my "friends" property is an array of objects referencing another schema.

Now here is my query :

```
dbModels.User
.find({ _id: req.session.user._id })
.populate('friends._friend', 'email birthdate')
.exec(function (err, _user){
  if (err || !_user){
    apiUtils.errorResponse(res, sw, 'Error when fetching friends.', 500);
  } else {

    console.log('user', _user);
    // This output the object with all its properties

    console.log('user birthdate', _user.birthdate);
    // _user.birthdate is undefined

    console.log('user friends', _user.friends);
    // _user.friends is undefined

    apiUtils.jsonResponse(res, sw, _user);
  }
});
```

When this web service return '_user', each properties are well defined and have the correct values.
The problem is that I only want to return _user.friends which is not possible since it's undefined.

Now, here is apiUtils.jsonResponse function :

```
exports.jsonResponse = function (res, sw, body) {

  console.log(body.friends);
  // At this breakpoint, body.friends is still undefined

  (sw || _sw).setHeaders(res);
  if (util.isArray(body)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
      body[i] = exports.cleanResults(body[i]);
    }
  } else {

    console.log(body.friends);
    // At this breakpoint body.friends is still undefined

    body = exports.cleanResults(body);
  }
  res.send(httpCode || 200, JSON.stringify(body));
};
```

And the cleanResults function :

```
exports.cleanResults = function (body) {

  console.log(body.friends);
  // At this point, body.friends is FINALLY DEFINED

  if (typeof body.toObject === 'function') {
    body = body.toObject();
    delete body.__v;
  }

  for (var attr in body) {
    if (body.hasOwnProperty(attr) && attr[0] == '_') {
      var _attr = attr.replace('_', '');
      body[_attr] = body[attr];
      delete body[attr];
    }
  }
  return body;
};
```

I tried to set a timeout to see if the problem came from async but it changed nothing. I'm a bit desesperate at this time and I wanted to know if you already encountered the same problem before ?

Comment: did the friend get shown properly in the console.log of the whole user object? did you console.log the friends object everywhere and it outputted undefined expect for in the cleanResults method?

Comment: Hi materik and thanks you.
When I print the whole user object, user.friends get already populated, everythings fine.
Yes I outputed user.friends at each of my comments and it was undefined until the cleanResults method.

Comment: Ok. give me a moment. I will try to repro it.

Comment: found the issue :p see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your problem, you have accidentally used `find` when you expect only one object to be returned. In this case, you should use `findById`:

```
User
    .findById(req.session.user._id)
    .populate('friends._friend', 'name surname picture birthdate')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        ...
    })
```

Comment: Thank you a lot it's working like a charm !! I can't figure out why `find` is not working since some requests can expect one or many objects to be returned...

Comment: find will return a list of users, you could have used find by then you would have add users returned and you had to get one of the users like so: var user = users[0], or something.

Comment: aaaah I didn't notice the array brackets at the time I printed the whole user object. Thank you !!!